# Tar remote dir without leading ./ on files

Tags: linux, tar

I have several scripts that run and collect data which is then fed into other scripts. So this entire chain is automated. At one point in the automation, all data files are tarred up to be sent for processing. The command I am using is this:

`tar -zchvf "$target_dir" -C "$data_dir" .`

Where target_dir is where my tarball is going and data_dir is where my data is located.

Now this is working fine; however, the files in my tarball look like this:

```
./file1
./file2
 <etc>
```

The post processing script is messing up because of the leading ./ on these files. It is expecting them to look like this:

```
file1
file2
<etc>
```

I have looked at the man page and nothing really stands out to me for removing the leading ./ in the tar process. One thing I was thinking about doing was changing the script to the following...

`cd $data_dir; tar -zchvf "$target" *; cd -`

but this just feels very wrong to me and I believe there is something else stupid I am missing.

I am using bash v3.2.5 just as reference.

Comment: I'd recommend instead of changing how the tarball is made to change how your post processing script checks for things. One option would be something like `tar -tf ${TARGET_FILE} | sed "s@^[./]*@@g"`

Comment: Or `tar ... | cut -c3-`

Comment: I was thinking about this. Thought it would be easier to fix the tar than the untar though. Will look to see how difficult this is.

Comment: Use `star`, it strips off leading `./` since 35 years.

Comment: @roaima that only changes the way its print to the term not how its put into the actual tar

Comment: @schily Tried it but for the -C option you get an Invalid transform expression error

Comment: @Sharki yes. But you talked about the post-processing having a problem handling the tarball files, so I (and @Centimane) offered a solution to that.

Comment: If you get such an error, you are using it wrong. The `-C` option needs to be very early in order to work and the message you mention is not in `star`. So your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @roaima the post processing processes the tarball not the output from the tarring command.....

Comment: Use `tar tf tarball | cut -c3-` then. Please _think_.

Comment: @schily What would be the correct command then?

Comment: Your example in the question looks correct. If you have problems, send the message. Notre that for data security reasons, star implements the -f key letter different than gtar and that gtar does not follow the tar command line. So better use -f separately.

Comment: n. b. it doesn't matter what shell you're using.

Comment: @roaima Just saying... You did not understand the question. Please read.

Comment: What if you did `tar -zchvf "$target_dir" -C "$data_dir"` instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you use gnu tar you can edit the filenames on the way into the tar:

```
$ mkdir -p a/b
$ cd a
$ tar cf - --transform='s:^./::' . | tar tvf - 
drwxr-xr-x        0 2018-07-24 18:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x        0 2018-07-24 18:18 b/
```

Comment: I would love to use the transform option since I know this works. But as I mentioned I am using bash 3.2.5 and tar 1.15.1 which does not have this available.

Comment: It makes no difference what version of `bash` you're using if you're looking at `tar` invocation.

Comment: I thought it would matter since different tar versions come with different shell versions.

Comment: @Sharki `tar` doesn't come with your shell, `tar` (and your shell) comes with your distro.

Comment: Fair enough - for the distro I am working with my tar version does not have that option.

Comment: And since you seem to be on Linux, your `tar` is not very TAR compatible. GNU tar intentionally uses a CLI that differs from the CLI of TAR. `star` when called as `star` also intentionally differs a bit from TAR, but when you call `star` as `tar`, you get 100% TAR CLI compatibility. This all is not related to the shell....

Comment: @schily I tried implementing the last thing you mentioned in the comments above to no avail. I am no expert at the tar command so I am trying to understand and learn this as I go along. You mentioned that the -f needs to be provided separately. I did this but I am still getting errors when providing the command a * for what to tar. I feel like there is something obvious that I am just not seeing atm.

Comment: As mentioned, `star` is closer to TAR than GNU tar is. The main difference is that `star` tries to prevent you from overwriting files as TAR output that you might believe is an input argument. Star gives helpful warnings and there is a man page:  http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html If you don't explain your problems, nobody could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Reading `tar 1.15.1`'s documentation,released 2004-12-21, from https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/ 's download link and its included `tar.info` to be sure:

> 6.3 Reading Names from a File
>   [...]
>
> --files-from=FILE NAME' `-T FILE NAME'
>        Get names to extract or create from file FILE NAME.
>
> If you give a single dash as a file name for '`--files-from`', (i.e.,
>   you specify either '`--files-from=-`' or '`-T -`'), then the file names
>   are read from standard input.

Now for `ls`, part of `coreutils`, reading `coreutil.info` from `coreutils-5.0` from 2003-04-02 (https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/), so predating `tar 1.15.1`:

> '`-A`'
>   '`--almost-all`'
>        List all files in directories except for '`.`' and '`..`'.

So this should work as wished (pair of parenthesis are there to forget the `cd`, you could probably do `cd -` instead or just not care):

```
( cd "$data_dir" && ls -A | tar -zchvf "$target_file" -T - )
```